# JavaFx FilteredList .setPredicate do not work

Tags: java, javafx-8

I'm trying to do a filter on TableView by a textfield in JavaFx same as this [example](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-sorting-filtering/).

Unfortunately I do not get any true returns. `.setPredicate` of `FilteredList` seems not running or is skip in debug mode.

```
public class App extends Application {

TableView tableScanSystemForSnapshots = new TableView<>(); 
private ObservableList<Snapshot> snapshots = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private FilteredList<Snapshot> filteredListSnapshots = new FilteredList<>(snapshots, s -> true);

public App() {

}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    //Table View Snapshots
    tableScanSystemForSnapshots.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE); //make multiple selection in TableView possible

    //Initialize Columns
    TableColumn<Snapshot, String> colVmName = new TableColumn<>("VM Name");
    TableColumn<Snapshot, String> colSnapshotName = new TableColumn<>("Snapshot Name");
    TableColumn<Snapshot, String> colSnapshotDescription = new TableColumn<>("Description");
    TableColumn<Snapshot, String> colCreatedTime = new TableColumn<>("created Time");
    TableColumn<Snapshot, String> colCreatedBy = new TableColumn<>("created by");

    //Initialize ValueFactory - name has to be the same as in Class: Snapshot
    colVmName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Snapshot, String>("vmName"));
    colSnapshotName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Snapshot, String>("snapshotName"));
    colSnapshotDescription.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Snapshot, String>("description"));
    colCreatedTime.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Snapshot, String>("createdTime"));
    colCreatedBy.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Snapshot, String>("createdBy"));

    //TextField Filter
    TextField txtFilter = new TextField();
    txtFilter.textProperty().addListener(((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        filteredListSnapshots.setPredicate(s -> {
            if(newValue == null||newValue.isEmpty()){
                return true;
            }
            //Compare
            String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase();

            if (s.getVmName().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)){return true;} //Filter matches VM Name
            if (s.getSnapshotName().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)){return true;} //Filter matches Snapshot Name
            return false; // Does not match
        });

        SortedList<Snapshot> sortedData = new SortedList<Snapshot>(filteredListSnapshots);
        sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(tableScanSystemForSnapshots.comparatorProperty());
        tableScanSystemForSnapshots.setItems(sortedData);
    }));
```

Comment: Your code works for me (after I changed the type of tableScanSystemForSnapshots to `TableView<Snapshot>` to get it to compile).  What version of Java are you using?

Comment: Hi VRG, I've just edited the line below, but still having the same effect. I use 1.8level8
    TableView<Snapshot> tableScanSystemForSnapshots = new TableView<Snapshot>();

Comment: It is difficult to help if we cannot reproduce your problem.  Consider editing your question so the code is a short but complete stand-alone program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: [Edit] the question to include a [MCVE]. As it stands it is not possible for anyone to provide an answer.

Answer (score -1):

The ObservableList snapshots was not filled correctly, after correcting that, it's working properly.